# How to bypass "Your connection isn't private" in Edge

Tags: google-chrome, https, microsoft-edge

```
Your connection isn't private

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I got this error in the mini app I am working for. In chrome, I can click Advanced button and proceed, then I can bypass this error. However, I could not find the proceed button in Edge, where I can find this button? Please kindly note that this only happened for the testing environments in the company.

Comment: You should see a similar kind of option in the Edge browser to proceed as you see in Google Chrome. could you please inform us which exact version of the Edge browser you are using? Further, please share the screenshot of the Edge browser window which show the error. It could help us understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT, the issue got resolved now. It is not related to Edge itself and it is a code issue.

Comment: It is great to know that the issue got resolved.